# How can I mimic a used magazine cover (crease, earmark, cracks) with Gimp?

Tags: png, book, filter, script, merge

I have made a fan magazine cover with Gimp (Sunken novels):

[image]

I would like to imitate creases, cracks, earmarks, tears (maybe even coffee mug marks) to give it a used, worn-out look. Something like:

[image]

I marked the places of wanna be creases, earmark, tears and cracks with black marker. Any pre-made existing filters, script-fus, or maybe another software, web app, or simply a transparent PNG with the creases and tears which I can merge / blend onto the magazine coover?

Answer (score 5):

You could use a paper texture. Either find an old worn piece of paper and scan it, or find a texture to use online, then paste it on its own layer above the main image layer, and change the blending mode to Multiply.

For example:

[image]

Comment: As far as I understand: should I scan a worn-out booklet which has completely white / beige cover and has the creases, cracks, earmarks to use then the multiply blend mode?

Comment: @Konstantin - any piece of suitably worn/creased paper will do.